# VBA "subscript out of range" in loop of variable length. Cannot locate issue

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to create a program which takes a variable number of players (denoted by (NumPlayerText.Value - 1)) and has them roll a die (NumThrowText.Value - 1) times. The values for each players rolls will be summed and compared, with the highest winning.

During the function, a loop designed to simulate (NumThrowText-1) dice rolls and add the values malfunctions ONLY when the number of players is higher than the number of rolls.

Here's the two interacting functions.

```
Function rollsumvalue(playernum)

Dim rolls()
ReDim rolls(NumThrowText.Value - 1)
ReDim rollsum(NumPlayerText.Value - 1)

    For playernum = 0 To (NumThrowText.Value - 1)
        rolls(playernum) = rolls(playernum) + random_generator(1, 6)
    Next
    rollsum(playernum) = (WorksheetFunction.Sum(rolls(playernum)))

End Function

Private Function callrollsumvalue()

For player = 0 To (NumPlayerText.Value - 1)
    rollsumvalue (player)
    MsgBox ("Rolled a total " & rollsum(player) & " points")
Next

End Function
```

rollsum is a global variable different than rolls FYI.

Debug shows **subscript out of range** from
`rolls(playernum) = rolls(playernum) + random_generator(1, 6)`

However I cannot see why this occurs only when # of players > # of rolls

Sorry for the long question. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does `Debug.Print NumThrowText.Value - 1)` return? What is the value of `playernum`?

Comment: First of all: You reset rollsum with each call of rollsumvalue (`redim rollsum(NumPlayerText.Value - 1)`); like this it doesn't make sense to have it as a global variable. Furthermore you are dimming rolls based on `NumThrowText.Value - 1` but use playernum as index for adding the random value. I think it would be sufficient if you have roll as a long-variable ..

Comment: These functions don't return anything ... they should be `Sub`s. Also "rollsum is a global variable"... red flag.

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware that I made some changes:

I am using two consts for NumThrows and NumPlayers as I don't have your input boxes.

I switched the order of the routines - it is usual to have the calling sub above the called function.

`rollSumValue` now returns the value for the player which then can be added to PlayersRollsum.

Within `rollSumValue` I am using a long variable to store the result - there is no need to store that value in an array.

If you want to re-use `PlayersRollsum` then you can change `playAllPlayers` to a function that returns `PlayersRollsum` as a result - but then you should think about a new name, like e.g. `getAllPlayerResults`. By that you avoid the global variable.

```vb
Option Explicit


Private Const NumThrows As Long = 5
Private Const NumPlayers As Long = 10

Public Sub playAllPlayers()

Dim PlayersRollsum(NumPlayers - 1) As Long

Dim playerNum As Long
For playerNum = 0 To NumPlayers - 1
    PlayersRollsum(playerNum) = rollSumValue(playerNum)
    MsgBox "Player " & playerNum & " rolled a total of " & PlayersRollsum(playerNum) & " points"
Next

End Sub

Private Function rollSumValue(playerNum As Long) As Long

Dim rolls As Long
Dim j As Long
For j = 1 To NumThrows
    rolls = rolls + random_generator(1, 6)
Next

rollSumValue = rolls

End Function
```